# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when making request to server IP

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, ssl-certificate, cross-domain

I got a nodeJS express API /w nginx up and running on an ubuntu server. I've set up everything but when I try to access the API (https://167.xx.xx.xx:80/get-all-products) directly or through my client I get this error:

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I've did some searching and I found out that this could be because my server does not have a valid ssl certificate but for a ssl certificate I would need to have a domain / be the owner of the ip adress which I guess i'm not as the server is hosted by another company.

How can I fix this error without having to buy a domain for my server?

Answer (score 1):

> `https://167.xx.xx.xx:80/...` ...
> I've did some searching and I found out that this could be because my
> server does not have a valid ssl certificate

This isn't the case here yet. The problem instead is that you are simply trying to switch from `http://` on port 80 to `https://` on port 80 without having the server setup for HTTPS. Thus the client will try to speak HTTPS while the server only understands HTTP - and this causes the failure you see.

To be able to use `https://` in the URL you need to setup the server for this and the configuration must use a certificate which matches the URL (domain or IP) - no way around this.